# macOS: Selecting items from a list by typing on the keyboard

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nscollectionview

The `NSTableView` has a feature, called *Type Selection*, by which the user can type the first letters of a listed item and the view automatically selects the first hit and scrolls to it.

I like to have a similar functionality in a `NSCollectionView`, where I list images by name.

Before I start writing such code by myself, I wonder if there is an API that can help me with this.

I am especially worred about getting the timing right, as I want to have it use the same timing as the `NSTableView` does. I imagine that it even changes depending on the user's System Preferences for typing. Also, the NSTableView will select other items with the same typed prefix if waiting long enough. All this can get quite complicated if I want to get it right. I don't want to miss anything.

Comment: Hi Thomas! I think you’re going to have to roll your own, and I think (as you say) it isn’t going to be trivial...

Comment: Hi Matt! Yeah. Maybe I'll just manage a hidden NSTableView in the background - although, can I send keypresses to it, then?